# Reverse permutation, number of inversions, descents, major index

Tags: combinatorics

If $w=a_1a_2...a_n \in S_n $, then let $w^r=a_n....a_2a_1$, the reverse of $w$. Express inv($w^r$), des($w^r$) and maj($w^r$) in terms inv($w$), des($w$), maj($w$), respectively.
It from Stanley's book, Enumerative Combinatorics.

$des(w) = |\lbrace  i\in [n-1]: w_i>w_{i+1} \rbrace |$,$maj(w)=\sum _{i\in D(w)} i $

I found $des(w^r)$=$n-1-des(w)$ and $inv(w^r)=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} - inv(w)$. I don't know how to express $maj(w^r)$ in term $maj(w)$.

Comment: how do you define $D(w)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all let's define $\text{D}(w)$ and $\text{D}(w^r)$ carefully, and we will add to that $\text{D}^+(w)$ in the same way as $D(w)$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}\text{D}(w)&=\lbrace  i\in [n-1]: &w_i>w_{i+1} \rbrace \tag 1\\
  \text{D}(w^r)&=\lbrace  i\in [n-1]: &w^r_i=w_{n+1-i}>w_{n+1-(i+1)}=w^r_{i+1} \rbrace \tag 2\\
\text{D}^+(w)&=\lbrace  i\in [n-1]: &w_i<w_{i+1} \rbrace \tag 3
\end{align}$$

The second set can be rewritten in a different way, we just take $j=n+1-(i+1)$  and get:
$$ \text{D}(w^r) =\lbrace  n-j \in [n-1]: w_{j}<w_{j+1} \rbrace  \tag 4$$

If you look at the assertion $(4)$ you can notice that the number of elements in $\text{D}(w^r)$ is exactly the number of elements in $\text{D}^+(w)$ as $j\to n-j$ is a bijection between the two sets, so we can write:
$$\left|\text{D}(w^r)\right|=\left|\text{D}^+(w) \right| \tag 5$$
And of course because $\text{D}(w)\cup \text{D}^+(w)=[n-1] $ and $\text{D}(w)\cap \text{D}^+(w)=\varnothing $ we get the first result :
$$\text{des}(w)+\text{des}(w^r)=|\text{D}(w)|+ |\text{D}(w^r)|=|[n-1]|=n-1 \tag 6$$
hence :

> $$\boxed{\text{des}(w^r)=n-1-\text{des}(w)} \tag 7$$

Now for $\text{maj}$ it's just a matter of computation, we use the same bijection as in $(5)$ and we have :

$$\begin{align}
\text{maj}(w)+\text{maj}(w^r)&=\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)}i+\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w^r)}i\tag8\\ \\
&=\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)}i+\sum_{i\in \text{D}^+(w)}n-i\tag 9\\ \\
&=\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)}i-\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)}n-i+\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)\cup \text{D}^+(w)}n-i \tag{10}\\ \\
&=\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)}n + \sum_{i\in [n-1]}i \tag{11}\\ \\
&=n|\text{D}(w)|+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \tag{12}\\ \\
&=n\text{des}(w)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \tag{13}
\end{align}$$
From $(8)$ to $9$ we used the bijection $j\to n-j$ between $\text{D}(w^r)$ and $\text{D}^+(w)$, from $9$ to $10$ we removed the term $\sum_{i\in \text{D}(w)}n-i $ and added it to the second sum, and in the next step we combined the two fist sums and we used $\text{D}(w)\cup \text{D}^+(w)=[n-1] $ for the second sum (summing $n-i$ or $i$ over $[n-1]$ gives the same result) Anyway we get finally:

> $$\boxed{\text{maj}(w^r)=n\text{des}(w)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\text{maj}(w) }\tag{14} $$

Comment: But don't we have maj$(1243)=3$ and maj$(3421)=5$?

Comment: You are absolutely right there is a mistake in my answer (I corrected), I am wondering if it's me who wrote it it's a long time ago, anyway what you did is very important we should point out wrong answers thank you

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is incorrect: e.g. consider $w=4321$ and $w^{r} = 1234$. Using the above formula yields
\begin{align}
   \mbox{maj}(w^r)
   & = 4 \cdot \mbox{des}(4321) + \binom{4}{2} - \mbox{maj}(4321)\\
   & = 4 \cdot 3 + 6 - 6\\
   & = 12
\end{align}
while $\mbox{maj}(1234) = 0$. Here is how I derived the correct formula:

1. Let $S$ be the descent set of $w$.
2. Thus $A^r = \{n-i\mid i\in S\}$ is the ascent set of $w^r$, by the bijection discussed in the above answer.
3. Thus $S^r = [n-1] \setminus A^r$ is the descent set of $w^r$, since every index in $[n-1]$ is necessarily either a descent or an ascent.

We derive the formula like so:
\begin{align}
\mbox{maj}(w^r)
= & \sum_{i\in S^r} i & (4)\\
= & \sum_{i\in [n-1]} i - \sum_{i\in A^r} i & (5)\\
= & \binom{n}{2} - \sum_{i\in S} n-i & (6)\\
= & \binom{n}{2} - \sum_{i\in S} n + \sum_{i\in S} i & (7)\\
= & \binom{n}{2} - n \mbox{des}(w) + \mbox{maj}(w) & (8)
\end{align}
(4) is the definition of major index.

(5) applies statement (3): since $S^r\cup A^r = [n-1]$, $\sum S^r + \sum A^r = \sum[n-1]$.

(6) uses the fact that the sum of $[n-1]$ is $\binom{n}{2}$ to simplify the first sum, and uses statement (2) to put the second in terms of $S$.

(7) splits the remaining sum into two terms.

(8) applies the definition of descent number and the major index.

The formula you desire is thus
$$ \bbox[2px,border:1px solid black]{\mbox{maj}(w^r) = \binom{n}{2} + \mbox{maj}(w) - n\mbox{des}(w)} $$